# FFMPEG: Transparent background with 'showwaves' or 'showspectrum'

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to render a video spectrum of music using `showwaves` ... I need it to render with a *transparent* background (i think this is called an alpha channel?)...

I tried `yuva420p` but it's still rendering a black background... here's what I'm doing:

```
ffmpeg -i music.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showwaves=s=1920x1080:mode=line:colors=white:draw=full,format=yuva420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a output.mp4;
```

Can anyone help? I know I'm close...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default codec for MP4 is x264 which does not support alpha channel. Use PNG.

```
ffmpeg -i music.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showwaves=s=1920x1080:mode=line:colors=white:draw=full,format=rgbap[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v png output.mp4;
```

Comment: i actually found another method with qtrle and colorchannelmixer that works too ... still learning ffmpeg and not sure there's a significant difference since it gives me the output i want (although the files MOV files created by qtrle are HUGE!)

Comment: @AK, thank you here = voting up (click on the upper triangle) and / or accepting the answer (click on the check mark).

Comment: done so :) ... just learning the ropes

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after hours of research... this also works to give me a transparent background:

`qtrle` and `colorchannelmixer` got me there on my own:

````
ffmpeg -i music.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showwaves=s=1920x1080:mode=line:colors=white:draw=full,colorchannelmixer=1:0:0:0:0:1:0:0:0:0:1:0:0.3:0.3:0.3:0" \
-map 0:a -c:v qtrle -an outputWaves.mov;```
````

Comment: The ccc filter is not necessary. Add `format=rgba` instead.

Comment: while this is absolutely correct, i'm bringing the files into screenflow which apparently can't import the `rgba` format. I had to use `qrtle` to get them to import properly.